# Android Zxing scanner fail scanning barcode in portrait mode

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, barcode, zxing

I am trying to make Zxing to scan barcode in portrait mode. The following is what I found and it worked in scanning QRcode. However, it DOES NOT scan 1D type code(Barcode for example). In the code, I think the image has been transformed for 90 degree.

However, When I scan the barcode(like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:UPC-A-036000291452.png), device must be turned to landscape mode and not on portrait mode. Or the scanner will never actually find anything....

Is there something I am missing, or I have to do some extra effort to transform the cam somewhere else?

(from https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178 )

1, manifest.xml, you need to make CaptureActivity portrait.

2, DecodeHandler.java, rotate data before buildLuminanceSource, it works because in YCbCr_420_SP and YCbCr_422_SP, the Y channel is planar and appears first

---

```
byte[] rotatedData = new byte[data.length];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        rotatedData[x * height + height - y - 1] = data[x + y * width];
```

---

3, CameraManager.java, getFramingRectInPreview() need to be modified.

---

```
rect.left = rect.left * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
rect.right = rect.right * cameraResolution.y / screenResolution.x;
rect.top = rect.top * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
rect.bottom = rect.bottom * cameraResolution.x / screenResolution.y;
```

---

4, CameraConfigurationManager.java, set camera orientation to portrait in setDesiredCameraParameters() use

---

```
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
```

---

and in getCameraResolution(), you need to swap x and y, because camera preview size is something like 480*320, other than 320*480.

---

```
int tmp = cameraResolution.x;
cameraResolution.x = cameraResolution.y;
cameraResolution.y = tmp;
return cameraResolution;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rotate the preview bytes you get from the camera preview. Use the function you have written in the 2nd point of your's. There is no need to do point 1, 3, 4 or 5.